# Nothing to publish for tag [Charts_assets]

Tags: laravel

I installed everything using the steps that they provided.

I ran composer equire consoletvs/charts on the package . This installed into the vendor folder.
I then added the ConsoleTVs\Charts\ChartsServiceProvider::class,into the provider in config/app and 'charts'=>ConsoleTVs\Charts\Charts::class, as an aliases..
I ran  artisan vendor:publish --tag=charts_config, the config file created successfully and I had no problems.

I ran php artisan vendor:publish --tag=charts_assets --force

But I kept on getting: Nothing to publish for tag [[charts_assets]]. which has lead me to thinking that this could be the problem since the package is not published.
any solution to solve this problem ?

Comment: as mentioned in documentation there are no tag named charts_assets, you have to choose one library from supported libraries and include the cdn into your html footer area
or you can download the js file and include it in your app.js if you are using wepback.  

Aafter including the library you can use the artisan command like this from doc 

"php artisan make:chart {Name} {Library?}"

for more information 
https://charts.erik.cat/create_charts.html#create-a-chart-class

Comment: So you ran `vendor:publish` once and the second time it says there is nothing to publish? Seems correct behavior to me...